# My table content starts fine then gets all messed up together in one line (Node.js, MongoDB)

Tags: html, css, node.js, mongodb, html-table

This is what I'm talking about:

[image: Table]

Why is that happening? Is it a styling problem? I tried adding some width to both tr and tds and it looks the same.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellido</th>
            <th>Mail</th>
            <th>Confirmado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<% personas.forEach(function(personas){ %>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%=personas.id%></td>
            <td><%=personas.nombre%></td>
            <td><%=personas.apellido%></td>
            <td><%=personas.email%></td>
            <td><%=personas.confirmado%></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the forEach after `<tbody>`. You want for example 'x' rows but not 'x' `<tbody>`
Then, end tag should come before `</tbody>`. Something like this:

```
    <tbody>
    <% personas.forEach(function(personas){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=personas.id%></td>
            <td><%=personas.nombre%></td>
            <td><%=personas.apellido%></td>
            <td><%=personas.email%></td>
            <td><%=personas.confirmado%></td>
        </tr>
    <% }); %>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The end of foreach must be in between `</tbody>` and `</table>`

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much you too!